# Find a string in web query without putting webpage contents on the sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a webquery within a macro.

```
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

The above line puts the webpage contents in the active worksheet. Then I find a string "approved" with the code given below

```
Set findRng = Cells.Find(What:="approved", After:=ActiveCell, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

If the string is found, I do some job with the code given below

```
If Not findRng Is Nothing Then 
    'do some job
End If
```

Can I find the word `approved` directly from memory or some kind of array without putting the contents of the webpage in the sheet and if yes, how?

Comment: Is the source HTML or XML or something other? Can you provide the URL?

Comment: its on intranet server that cannot be accessed publicly :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Function GetResponseText(url as String) as String
  Dim objHttp As Object
  objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  objHttp.Open("GET", url, False) 
  objHttp.Send("")
  GetResponseText = objHttp.ResponseText
End Function
```

GetResponseText contains the html as text (full scripting)
search with:

```
If instr(GetResponseText([your url]), "approved") > 1 Then
  'your code if approved
Else
  'your code if not
End If
```

you may check the string of 'GetResponseText' and search for ">approved<" or something like that

Comment: I had tried this approach already however it doesn't work. For the string to be displayed, it requires me to login to that site, the response text doesnot show that string even if im logged in with cookies in

Comment: The server version of MSXML2 is not available on desktop versions of Windows.

Comment: The Open method is not a function. The Send method is not a function.

Comment: it worked for me... need to doublecheck it...
you may look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958472/vba-msxml2-serverxmlhttp-response-text-is-an-html-page

Comment: It works but it doesnt fetches the proper html source. The source is different if the user is logged in or logged out. Your method gets the source in responsetext but as guest and not as logged in member hence the string what i am looking for is not retrieved. i hope i am making sense

Comment: try: `objHttp.Open("GET", url, False, "username", "password") `