# How to deal with refresh more than one external data source in excel at the same time?

Tags: vba, excel, web, excel-2013

So I've got one excel sheet which has four external data source, the data is live stock quotes & other information from my broker website.

The problem is my broker website allows adding maximum 50 stocks only per watch-list but I have more than 150 stocks to track so I made four such watch-list but the problem is now it takes bit of more time when data gets refresh every minute (I'm also storing that data in excel) and process is not smooth enough.

It is also very cumbersome when making changes to formula or doing any edit as I have to wait till refresh ends.

Is there any way so that all the four watch list can refresh at the same time in excel so that processing become quicker?

Comment: Generally people just pay their brokers for higher access.

Comment: I have higher excess on my broker terminal but when I asked them about their website watchlist adding more than 50 stocks they told me it is not possible as coding has not been that way. Also the thing is that I just want to store data every minute in excel because it is necessary for my algorithm.

Comment: You simply can't run multiple data-imports at the same time. So either do it in a different importing way like [ResponseText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417502/find-a-string-in-web-query-without-putting-webpage-contents-on-the-sheet/) which is at least a lot faster or run an external script to save everything to a local drive and import it afterwards (which schould be also much quicker)

Comment: Thank you very much Dirk I'll look into these options

Comment: I would take a different excel sheets for your importing and for your algorithm. And let the importing sheet overwrite the previous results. In that way you always have all the data for your algorithm.

Comment: Thanks Luuklag but will it help for real-time processing? Because my data workbook will be different & formula workbook will be different. Right now I receive data in four different sheets and formulas are in the fifth one in the same workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Excel really isn't the right tool for analyzing over 150 stocks.  However, if you really want to get that many prices free and quickly, run the script below.

Notice, the first ticker starts in row 7.

```
Sub GetData()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim yahoourl As String
    Dim QuerySheet As Worksheet
    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim qurl As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set DataSheet = ActiveSheet

    i = 7
    yahoourl = "http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + Cells(i, 1)
    i = i + 1
    While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        yahoourl = yahoourl + "+" + Cells(i, 1)
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    yahoourl = yahoourl + "&f=" + "l1"

Columns("C:C").Select
Range("C2").Activate
On Error Resume Next
Selection.QueryTable.Delete
Selection.ClearContents

QueryQuote:
             With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & yahoourl, Destination:=DataSheet.Range("C7"))
                .BackgroundQuery = True
                .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                .SaveData = True
            End With

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 28#
    Cells(2, 3).Select

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```