# Retrieving min. value from website via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I very recently started learning VBA and is facing some difficulties in scraping data. I would like to retrieve the daily minimum flight price from Singapore to Bangkok.

My current code is only able to retrieve the first line of code referencing to "formattedTotalPrice" in the website source code, which might not be the minimum price. Would be really grateful if someone could help a newbie out!

```
Sub GetPrices()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim pth As String
pth = "https://www.expedia.com.sg/Flights-Search?rfrr=TG.LP.SrchWzd.Flight&langid=2057&trip=OneWay&leg1=from:Singapore,%20Singapore%20(SIN-Changi),to:Bangkok,%20Thailand%20(BKK-Suvarnabhumi%20Intl.),departure:" & date & "TANYT&passengers=children:0,adults:1,seniors:0,infantinlap:Y&options=cabinclass:economy,sortby:price,carrier:&mode=search&paandi=true"

Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
XMLHTTP.Open "GET", pth, False
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
XMLHTTP.send
buf = XMLHTTP.ResponseText

Locn_price = InStr(1, buf, "formattedTotalPrice\")
Locn_end = InStr(Locn_price, buf, "totalPriceAsDecimal\")
trim_price = Mid(buf, Locn_price + 27, Locn_end - 32 - Locn_price)
Debug.Print trim_price

ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Value = Date
ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = trim_price

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Date need to be formatted DD/MM/YYYY: Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")

```
pth = "https://www.expedia.com.sg/Flights-Search?rfrr=TG.LP.SrchWzd.Flight&langid=2057&trip=OneWay&leg1=from:Singapore,%20Singapore%20(SIN-Changi),to:Bangkok,%20Thailand%20(BKK-Suvarnabhumi%20Intl.),departure:" & Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "TANYT&passengers=children:0,adults:1,seniors:0,infantinlap:Y&options=cabinclass:economy,sortby:price,carrier:&mode=search&paandi=true"
```

Comment: ah thank you! Any idea how to extract the minimum price from here?

Comment: The preferred method would be to create an HTML Document from the 
 responseText and then find the elements of the Document that have the information that you want.  The answer to [VBA MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP Response text is an HTML Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958472/vba-msxml2-serverxmlhttp-response-text-is-an-html-page) will show you how to create an HTML Document.

Comment: You will need to search the list items of `<ul id="flightModuleList">` to find the information of each flight.

Comment: You can still do it your way you will just have to create a loo and change the starting location of the `Instr` function:   'Locn_price = InStr(Locn_price , buf, "formattedTotalPrice\"'.  You will also have to initiate the `Locn_price = 1` before the loop.