# How to extract min. value from source code using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I very recently started learning VBA and is facing some difficulties in scraping data. I would like to retrieve the daily minimum flight price from Singapore to Bangkok via Expedia.

My current code is only able to retrieve the first line of code referencing to "formattedTotalPrice" in the website source code, which might not be the minimum price, and all words flanking prices are identical. Would be really grateful if someone could help a newbie out!

```
Sub GetPrices()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim pth As String
pth = "https://www.expedia.com.sg/Flights-Search?rfrr=TG.LP.SrchWzd.Flight&langid=2057&trip=OneWay&leg1=from:Singapore,%20Singapore%20(SIN-Changi),to:Bangkok,%20Thailand%20(BKK-Suvarnabhumi%20Intl.),departure:" & DateAdd("d", 1, Date) & "TANYT&passengers=children:0,adults:1,seniors:0,infantinlap:Y&options=cabinclass:economy,sortby:price,carrier:&mode=search&paandi=true"


Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
XMLHTTP.Open "GET", pth, False
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
XMLHTTP.send
buf = XMLHTTP.ResponseText

Locn_price = InStr(1, buf, "formattedTotalPrice\")
Locn_end = InStr(Locn_price, buf, "totalPriceAsDecimal\")
trim_price = Mid(buf, Locn_price + 27, Locn_end - 32 - Locn_price)

ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Value = Date
ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = trim_price

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving min. value from website via VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931687/retrieving-min-value-from-website-via-vba)